# .map() is not a function Error on Mapping Dynamically created Object

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I am trying to map a dynamically created Object to an Array like this

```
          params.junctionBarriers = dojo.toJson(junctionBarriers);
          // printing the object in the console (Please look at attached image)
          console.log(params.junctionBarriers);

          var value = [];
          var data = params.junctionBarriers.map(function (s) {
             value.push(webMercatorUtils.xyToLngLat(s.x, s.y, true));
              return s;
          })
```

but I am getting this error

> params.junctionBarriers.map is not a function

[image]

As you can see from the image the `params.junctionBarriers` is dynamically loaded but the `.map()` is not valid. Why is this, and how I can fix it?

Comment: is `junctionBarrieres` an Array? Your console statement is not conclusive, it could be just the internal string representation.

Comment: no it looks like another object

Comment: Well, luckily you got 2 good answers already :)

Comment: @chsdk Was the tag [tag:dojo.tojson] really necessary? It's the only question that has it, and I am guessing it is part of [tag:dojo] itself ;)

Comment: @Icepickle yes indeed it's part of dojo itself, it's a function in dojo that can be used as a replacement for `JSON.stringify()`, I added it for the sake of future questions as well. ^_^

Comment: @chsdk That sounds a bit like an overkill to me, I cannot imagine having all functions as tags here, however, I don't find any guidelines to tag creation, so I just asked it as [a meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360271/tag-creation-guidelines)

Comment: @chsdk Are you sure you still want to keep the tag (seeing what the meta question turned up?)

Comment: [Link to meta discussion regarding the dojo.tojson tag, for reference.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360271/7079453)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Look at the documentation for dojo.toJson](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/toJson.html)

That method converts an object to a **string** in JSON format.

**A String does not have the method map**.

So why don't you simply do `junctionBarriers.map`? given you already have the array of objects in that variable (which is NOT params.junctionBarriers)

Answer (score 2):

Actually **[`dojo.toJson()`](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/toJson.html)** is the same as **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)**, which is converting your `array` to a JSON `string` here. So the problem is that you were trying to call `.map()` on a `string`.

That's why you got the error:

> params.junctionBarriers.map is not a function

So you need to make your `.map()` call before transforming your `object` to a JSON `string`.

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1: Don't use dojo.ToJson.
- Option 2: If you need to conovert your object to JSON string for some reason you will need to parse it back to an object before using .map

  ```
        // Option 1 params.junctionBarriers = junctionBarriers;
        // Option 2 params.junctionBarriers = JSON.parse(params.junctionBarriers);
         // printing the object in the console (Please look at attached image)
        console.log(params.junctionBarriers);

        var value = [];
        var data = params.junctionBarriers.map(function (s) {
           value.push(webMercatorUtils.xyToLngLat(s.x, s.y, true));
            return s;
        })
  ```

Comment: Why would we serialize an object then parse it again?! It's a little bit useless here.

Comment: That is why I suggested not ussing dojo.ToJson in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Do not check arrays with a `console.log()` you have a method called `Array.isArray(myArray)` that returns `true` or `false` depending if your variable is an array or not.

Actually your converting your `junctionBarriers` into an String so `params.junctionBarriers` is a String and you can't do a `.map()` to a String.

Try to look always in the documentation:

- [dojo.toJson()](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/toJson.html)
- [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/isArray)